# If condition doesn't output properly yet it compiles in C

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

So it compiles ok, but the output it is not the expected. The issue I think is in the OR operator which does not work properly, or it conflicts with the && operator. But perhaps it's bad written or something. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
if((len == 16) && secDigit == (51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55)
{
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    exit(0);
}

else if((len == 15) && secDigit == (34 | 37))
{
    printf("AMEX\n");
    exit(0);

}

else if((len == (16 | 13)) && firstDigit == 4)
{
    printf("VISA\n");
    exit(0);
}

else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `16 | 13` is `29`. Did you mean `(len == 16 || len == 13)` ?

Comment: Along with the apparent misunderstanding pointed out above, you also have a missing `)` at the end of your very first line of code.

Comment: Indeed @WeatherVane , appreciate it

Comment: I am sure you can solve the second one too. the first one is perhaps easier as `if(len == 16 && secDigit >= 51 && secDigit <= 55)`

Comment: Did the corrections suggested by @WeatherVane lead to the expected behavior?

Comment: I think you need to start from the C book and learn how the logical operations work

Comment: Yep @RobertoCaboni

Answer (score 0):

| is the Binary OR operator while what you need is || ,the Logical OR operator.

Syntax:

a|b
(Boolean 1) || (Boolean 2)

Note: Conditional operators evaluate to boolean values

```
if((len == 16) && (secDigit >= 51 && secDigit<= 55))
{
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    exit(0);
}

else if((len == 15) && (secDigit == 34 || secDigit == 37))
{
    printf("AMEX\n");
    exit(0);

}

else if((len == 16 || len == 13)) && firstDigit == 4)
{
    printf("VISA\n");
    exit(0);
}

else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
    exit(0);
```

}